# Hyper-threading and PER-CPU arrays

Tags: c, osdev

I have been trying to find an answer to this question, but I have not been able to:

Should PER-CPU arrays be sized after the number of physical cores, or the total cores (physical + siblings) in a system?

Siblings cannot execute at the same time as each other, but I guess they can preempt each others.

Say you are counting some statistic, and you have 100 cores + 100 siblings. Should the per-cpu array for this statistic be size 200 or can you save some space by making it 100 elements? Is there a way to do atomic-local operations in order to get away with 100 elements without locking cache lines? Perhaps something akin to restartable sequences for the sibling-local case?

Comment: By siblings you mean hyper-threads? Hyper-threads absolutely **can** execute at the same time as each other and you can't control that.

Comment: you should treat hyper threads just like any other processor.

Comment: So the answer is : PER-CPU arrays should be sized after the number of total cores (physical + siblings).